# How to use javascript to change text color on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am creating a web site for a snow cone stand and want to create a cool effect for their flavor list. I am curious how to approach this issue. When I hover over the text I'd like to set up an event listener for mouse enter that scales the text and fills the text with the correct color based on the real life fruit. How can I best achieve this without creating a variable for each flavor? (I have all the color classes created in css)

```
var flavorAdder = (function() {

var flavorArr1, flavorArr2, flavorArr3, flavorArr4, textLocator1, textLocator2, textLocator3, textLocator4, addToPage;

flavorArr1 = [
    '<p>Apple</p>',
    '<p>Banana</p>',
    '<p>Birthday Cake</p>',
    '<p>Black Cherry</p>'
];

flavorArr2 = [
    '<p>Green Apple</p>',
    '<p>Guava</p>',
    '<p>Honeydew Melon</p>',
    '<p>Huckleberry</p>'
];

flavorArr3 = [
    '<p>Peach</p>',
    '<p>Piña Coloda</p>',
    '<p>Pineapple</p>',
    '<p>Pink Grapefruit</p>'
];

flavorArr4 = [
    '<p>Pink Lemonade</p>',
    '<p>Red Raspberry</p>',
    '<p>Rootbeer</p>'
];

textLocator1 = document.querySelector('#flavorList1');
textLocator2 = document.querySelector('#flavorList2');
textLocator3 = document.querySelector('#flavorList3');
textLocator4 = document.querySelector('#flavorList4');


addToPage = function(arr, text) {
    arr.forEach(function(current) {
        text.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', current);
    });
}

addToPage(flavorArr1, textLocator1);
addToPage(flavorArr2, textLocator2);
addToPage(flavorArr3, textLocator3);
addToPage(flavorArr4, textLocator4);


})();
```

Comment: Can you give us the HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because you asked for JS, but you can create a psuedoclass for this.  i.e. `.apple:hover{font-size: 50em; color: blue;}` would work if the original class is `.apple{font-size: 10em; color: red; transition: .25s} `.  Tell me if you want this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't JS, but it can be easily solved using a CSS pseudoclass `:hover`.

If the class `.apple` is `.apple{font-size: 10em; color: red; transition: .25s}`, then you can make a pseudoclass `.apple:hover{font-size: 50em; color: blue;}` to do the animation.